# Setting Environment Variables from UDEV

Tags: usb, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04, udev

I have a few different devices which all accomplish the same basic task. I would like to be able to swap them, and regardless of which one is plugged in, have the same symlink. For example, if I have device1, device2, and device3 and I plug one in to my computer, I want a symlink to be created that is called my_device. However I would like programs running on my computer to know which one is plugged in, preferably through the use of an environment variable, i.e. MY_DEVICE_ID="1".

This is what I have so far:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb" ATTRS{...}=="...", SYMLINK+="my_device", ENV{MY_DEVICE_ID}="1"

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb" ATTRS{....}=="....", SYMLINK+="my_device", ENV{MY_DEVICE_ID}="2"

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb" ATTRS{.....}==".....", SYMLINK+="my_device", ENV{MY_DEVICE_ID}="3"
```

Note: Only one device will ever be plugged in at a time. These rules correctly create the symlink, however an environment variable is never set. Why not, and what can I do to accomplish this?

Thanks for your help!

Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

The scope of the variable assigned in the `udev` rule is limited to the `udev` environment itself. You need to use another facility to make your data available to other programs.

Comment: I was afraid that was the case. Do you have any thoughts on other facilities I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: for example you could create another symlink with the device id embedded and then check that

Comment: Yes I suppose you could do that. Unfortunately that would lead to a lot of if statements trying to see which symlink exists, which isn't desirable. Thank you for your suggestion though!